# Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'DataContext accessed after Dispose.'

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Cannot access a disposed object.

```
Object name: 'DataContext accessed after Dispose.'.
```

while providing parametrs in LINQ
Below is code

```
EmployeeMasterBL _EmployeeMasterBL = new EmployeeMasterBL();
tblEmployeeMaster _tblEmployeeMaster =  _EmployeeMasterBL.SelectEmpName_EmpID(Convert.ToInt64(emdStudID));
tblEmployeeClockedIn _tblEmployeeClockedIn = new tblEmployeeClockedIn();

if (objScanCard.InOut == 1)
{

    //Insert record in Employee clock In  in Employee clocked In Table

    _tblEmployeeClockedIn.EmpCode = _tblEmployeeMaster.EmpCode;
    _tblEmployeeClockedIn.FirstName = _tblEmployeeMaster.FirstName;
    _tblEmployeeClockedIn.LastName = _tblEmployeeMaster.LastName;
    _tblEmployeeClockedIn.ScanDate = objScanCard.ScanDate;
    _tblEmployeeClockedIn.ScanTime = objScanCard.ScanTime;

    ****_tblEmployeeClockedIn.JobTitle = _tblEmployeeMaster.tblJobTitleMaster.JobTitle;****
    flgMissedClkIn = objScanCardBL.InsertEmployeeClockedIn(_tblEmployeeClockedIn);
}
```

on this line :

`****_tblEmployeeClockedIn.JobTitle = _tblEmployeeMaster.tblJobTitleMaster.JobTitle;****`

i am getting error like

> Cannot access a disposed object.  Object name: 'DataContext accessed
>   after Dispose.'.

Any help...!??

Comment: can you post the code that you are using in this method_EmployeeMasterBL.SelectEmpName_EmpID(Convert.ToInt64(emdStudID));

Comment: I am not sure, but you have already disposed **tblJobTitleMaster** datacontext object. Check with the object yourself, or put a code for that too.

Comment: your tblEmployeeMaster is probably created within a using ()